# "Add to cart" with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

### The goal

Copy one text and move him to another element.

### The problem

I have a list of products on my application and I want to add them in a summary when I click on "add button". Until here, easy, huh?!

The product on summary will be displayed with his name and quantity. So I ask: How can I extract this name from DOM and "paste" in a new place?

But... *wait!* The problem becomes big when the "add" button is outside of product element. I mean, the "add button" is inside of a tooltip that is on the bottom of the code — has no relationship to the element of the product.

### What I thought to do

The tooltip has the follow structure:

```
<div class="tooltip">
   <form action="">
      <input type="text" name="product_quantity" />
      <button type="submit" />
   </form>
</div>
```

And I thought to do the following:

```
<div class="tooltip">
   <form action="">
      <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="1" />
      <input type="text" name="product_quantity" />
      <button type="submit" />
   </form>
</div>
```

And then, through jQuery, get an element with that value (in our case, **1**).

### My official code

You can see it on [FiddleJS](http://jsfiddle.net/chiefGui/k4NEF/) or above:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="product-header">
            <h1>Cap</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="product-body">
            <p>A beautiful cap</p>
        </div>
        <div class="product-controls">
            <a href="#">Click here to open the tooltip to select a quantity then add to products summary</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="product-header">
            <h1>Gears of War — The game</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="product-body">
            <p>TPS by Microsoft Studios</p>
            <div class="product-controls">
                <a href="#">Click here to open the tooltip to select a quantity then add to products summary</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tooltip" style="display: none;">
    <form action="">
        <input type="text" name="product_quantity" />
        <button type="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

### (UPDATE) Maybe... AJAX?!

I got to thinking about the possibility of recovering the product identifier (by tooltip's input hidden) and make a query to the database — but it would be feasible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: that's what I do, on the 'add to cart' button you have the product id, then you add the product in to the cart in the ajax request, then this ajax request will return the product name and every thing you might need. You have to add the product to the cart anyway, and as long as the ajax request is not done, it's not yet in your cart. So I thinks this is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

// get value of product id with jquery

```
$('.tooltip button').click(function() {
  alert($('#product_id').val());
});
```

If you want to use AJAX, try this http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/creating-a-slick-ajaxed-add-to-basket-with-jquery-and-php/

Answer (score 0):

I've written some months ago a similar thing based on jQuery: https://github.com/yckart/jquery.animateto.js

Here's a simple demo without any Ajax-request or else

http://yckart.github.com/jquery.animateto.js/

Comment: Hello, friend. Unfortunately, it is not about the animation or effect, but how to move DOM's data from one place to other place — can you understand?